# HTMLParser: Get data inside the <td> that follows another one

Tags: python, html-parsing, html-parser

I'm using Python's HTMLParser (Not a requirement per se, but it's better than an external library for corporate environment reasons) to extract a date from a huge table coming from a badly-developed software that looks like this excerpt:

```
(...)
<tr>
    <td class='resultLabel'>
        Scan Syntax
    </td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class='resultLabel'>Show Text</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class='resultLabel'>
        Snapshot
    </td>
    <td>
        05/05/15 11:25:16
        &nbsp;&nbsp;
        <span class='clickCursorRegular' title='View Transcript' onClick="viewStatusTranscript('714294386-2303', '0FB88F01-CDA1-ECFA-597C-93CA57C71910')">
        Succeeded
        </span>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class='resultLabel'>Snapshot OS Image</td>
    <td><span style='color:#636363;'>Not Supported</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class='resultLabel'>Telnet/SSH Session</td>
    <td>
        04/28/15 16:11:40
        &nbsp;&nbsp;
        <span class='clickCursorRegular' title='View Transcript' onClick="viewStatusTranscript('714294386-2303', '814FE794-7982-2334-E69F-4D8EF9615011')">Failed</span>
    </td>
</tr>
```

My goal is to get the date corresponding to the *Snapshot* field (In this case "05/05/15 11:25:16"), but **only** if the snapshot succeeded. (EDIT: I mean getting the date either way, but also knowing if it is a valid one by reading the "Successful" part)

This can be extracted from the text inside the  following the date. The containing table has no IDs or classes but it's the only table in the whole page, and the number of rows may fluctuate. FWIW, the HTML was obtained using Requests.

I've been looking at HTMLParser but I am not sure how to accomplish this task... Feel free to suggest another libraries although I'd really like to stick with Python's built-ins if possible due to corporate regulations.

Comment: The scenario is not 100% clear to me, but how about storing the date in a variable when you find it, then looking at the next element and if it shows success, use the stored date, else clear it?

Comment: Yeah, that's what I want to do. The issue here is that I don't know a reliable way to find the required data (The "successful" part)

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to do it. I haven't really found one with HTMLParser which really satisfies me, but I'm still looking! Here are some ideas:

- Just count the times a starttag `<td>` is found, then accept the data from the data handler
- Slightly improved version: Count starttags `<td>` which have an attribute `class='resultLabel'`
- Still somewhat better: Search for *nested* `<td>`s
- If you want detect several fields in a page, you can implement a `state machine`, to detect a certain sequence of tags.

You could also take all tags and construct a tree structure, which would allow you to address directly the branch where you expect the `<td>` to be.
That is what [lxml](http://lxml.de/parsing.html#parsing-html) does: In one single step, it parses the HTML document and converts it into a tree structure, which can then be navigated to the branch containing the `<td>` you need.

What's the main problem? Many, many websites produce pages which are incorrect. So it is up to the parser to be fault tolerant and accept certain strangeness. Most browsers accept that strangeness quietly, but you can check with the browser's debugger or send the url to w3c's validation service.